# Banner dismissal after concurrent edits

Tags: bug, edits, notification-bar

When the orange banner for notifications is dismissed, it leaves a blank space above the top bar.

This happened in IE8, with the notification for post having been edited by another user while I was in the process of editing it.

Possibly related to [this recent change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/)?

[image]

Comment: But... didn't that banner get burninated?

Comment: Not for everything. I got it because someone else edited the post I was editing while I was editing it, and I imagine it is probably lurking in a couple other places related to the page you are viewing rather than your account.

Comment: This blank space remains in place when encountered in /review and the next review item is opened, though it is correctly removed when leaving the queue.